# Dynamic Y-Axis scale for Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

In PowerBI, I have a column chart that has multiple hierarchal levels. I don't like the auto scale feature that PowerBI provides, so I want to create my own measure that returns the minimum y-value of the hierarchal level that is shown, and the same for the maximum value. I believe I was able to create the measures using several ISINSCOPE functions and a SWITCH function. Unfortunately, it is not working so I am trying to debug by having the measure output a constant value of 0.5 to see if the column chart is accepting it. I am applying the measure in the conditional formatting of (Visualizations > Format Visual > Y-Axis > Range > Minimum). It seems to have no effect on the column chart.

I know the measure it at least correctly outputting the value because if I applied to the chart as an input to the y-axis, then it shows columns of 50%.

So, what could be the problem here? Is the conditional formatting option not robust enough to accept my created measure? Is there any work around?

(I am a beginner in PowerBI)

EDIT:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTfsZTErcVx88UVpeogdqpFSImYEYSyQ/view?usp=drive_link

Sample dataset used to reproduce the error. The measure I am using is MinValue.

Comment: @DavideBacci Due to security reasons, I cannot, but I can attempt making a sample file.

Comment: @DavideBacci I have created a sample dataset to replicate my error. What is the best way for me to share this .pbix file?

Comment: Upload to an external site and update your question with the link

Comment: @DavideBacci Thank you, I have updated the post with the relevant link.

Comment: This is a bug - I would raise with Microsoft. ISFILTERED() works on labels and correctly shows true/false but it does not work when setting the min/max value of the y axis.